# What algorithms are needed to map displacement to base mesh?

Tags: algorithm, mesh, uv-mapping

By given belows,
Base mesh(vertices, faces, texture coordinates - UV map),
Normal map(1024x1024 image),
Displacement map(1024x1024 image), 
I want to make a mesh which reflects the displacement map. Since the vertices of the base mesh is not directly corresponds  to those maps, it seems that a re-meshing method based on the displacement map is required. Can someone tell me what method is applicable?